# Verb tenses question

Tags: conditional-constructions

I'm doing my homework and I can't figure out the answer of this exercise. It says:

> Even if I (...) I still wouldn't copy in a test.

A. Didn't study

B. Wouldn't study

C. Hadn't studied

I think the correct answer is C but I'm not really sure if it's A or C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even if I (...) I still wouldn't copy in a test.

This is presenting a *hypothetical situation*. When you make a hypothetical statement you normally first establish an unreal situation as either something that has happened in the *past* or describe a *present* situation. The words you use may be past or present but if it is just hypothetical as in your example ("Even if" implies that it is a hypothetical situation) then it is sometimes referred to as *the unreal past*. You would then go on to state what you *would* do, in future terms.

I believe the correct answer to your question is:

> Even if I **hadn't studied** I still wouldn't copy in a test.

This is because you are saying that if you had not studied (past tense) you would not cheat (future tense). Even if you were speaking about a future test where you might have the opportunity to study in the future, at the point you were taking the test any study opportunity would then be in the past.